# Drag-and-drop (un)favorite tags to make them in alphabetical order

Tags: discussion, feature-request, tags, sorting

I accidentally removed tag ('c++') from my favorites and when I re-added it, it appeared at the end of tags list. Prior to that it was near 'c' tag in favorites list. I cannot re-order these tags by dragging or anyhow else.
I've seen some questions about tag ordering but they seem to relate to something different from my situation.
Are there plans to enable some ordering tool for use-case I described? Or maybe tool aready there and I just overlooked it?

Comment: @Yi Jiang Yes, very likely. I couldn't find this question. Feel free to close as duplicate.

Comment: I removed my most favourite tag by using a mobile device and clicking the cross on the button with a big fat finger. I now have to scroll down every time I visit StackOverflow.

Answer (score 0):

I'm afraid the only available trick for now is to remove all the favorite tags and then readd them in order you want.

Of course it doesn't seem to be good solution but at least it works.